Change OpenAPI generator maven plugin log level to WARN
I am trying to change log levels for the openapi-generator-maven-plugin by adding *.properties and logback.xml files, but I have not been successful so far. I also haven't found any configuration property to enable this change. This plugin generates many INFO level logs that we want to suppress. Any suggestions would be helpful.
Explored plugin config options and changing logback, slf4j properties files.

Maven uses slfj-simple under the hood.
First run your build with -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showLogName=true so that you can see which classes the logs are coming from.
Then set log levels as desired by setting additional properties named -Dorg.slf4.simpleLogger.log.[[classname]]=[[level]].
